# How do I center image links on same line?

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, center

My goal is to align three links on the same line and center them. I thought this was the way to do it, but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

The CSS

```
.links_wrapper {
    margin:auto;
}
.home_links {
    float: left;
}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="links_wrapper">
    <div class="home_links">
        <a href="#"><img src="#"/></a>
    </div>

    <div class="home_links">
        <a href="#"><img src="#"/></a>
    </div>

    <div class="home_links">
        <a href="#"><img src="#"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: give them a width of 33% and make sure you normalize the CSS (or just put this: `*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; }` )

Comment: Is there a line of your HTML missing? Could you please add it.

Comment: Nope. That's all of the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*, 
*:before, 
*:after { 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.home_links {
    max-width: 33%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

Feel free to alter margins n stuff as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is because they are both in separate `div`s with `float:left;`. Putting them in a single `<div class="home_links">` tag should work once the `float:left;` is removed.

If you want the spacing to be equal between the links, setting a width percentage equal to `1/numberOfLinks` will solve give the `div`s an appropriate width. In this case, the `float:left;` should stay.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/99u6C/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="links_wrapper">
    <div class="home_links"> <a href="#"><img src="#"/></a>

    </div>
    <div class="home_links"> <a href="#"><img src="#"/></a>

    </div>
    <div class="home_links"> <a href="#"><img src="#"/></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.links_wrapper {
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
.home_links {
    display:inline-block;
}
```